# JavaCV how to check OpenCVFrameGrabber is available

Tags: java, javacv

I'm work on JavaFX desktop application which my main feature is based on webcam. I'm using JavaCV to camera capture.

I have a requirement for the application to works properly even if the camera is unavailable. If the camera is unavailable, it displays information about that, but the application is still working.

My problem is that when I get instance of `OpenCVFrameGrabber` I can't find a way to check if the OpenCVFrameGrabber from my internal webcam is available.

```
import org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber

OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
// grabber.isAvailable() - I'm searching for that method
```

I also tried to run `grabber.start()` method and catch the camera exception. This solution is not acceptable in my application, beacause if the camera is unavailable, the exception will be thrown a few seconds after calling the method and the thread is blocked (I'm waiting too long).

For testing the application in case the camera is unavailable I switch between the "Allow apps to access your camera" slider in Windows 10 settings.

[image]

Comment: OpenCV doesn't offer much capabilities in that regards. Please use VideoInputFrameGrabber instead for that.

Comment: @SamuelAudet Thanks for answer.





I still have problem, because in the app I am switching between built-in camera and external camera.






When I'm use `OpenCVFrameGrabber` I'm create two instances with `deviceNumber` 0 and 1. I switch between these instances to change the camera.






How to implement this with `VideoInputFrameGrabber`? I'm already have traid to switching between `deviceNumber` 0 and 1. It doesn't work in my case.

Comment: How doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: Now it works fine. I needed to change some code. I have one more question: it's posible to check name of camera?

Comment: Yes, try to call `VideoInputFrameGrabber.getDeviceDescriptions()`.

Comment: @SamuelAudet I have one more question. In the app I have requirements that app have to works on Windows, Linux and MacOS. On Windows everythings works properly but in Ubuntu 20.04 i got error: Platform "linux-x86_64" not supported by class org.bytedeco.videoinput.global.videoInputLib

Comment: Right, you'll need to use something else. FFmpegFrameGrabber itself doesn't expose a lot of the API from FFmpeg because it's pretty low level, but all that you need _should_ be there.

Comment: I also need a way to get the device name. I got followings error in every cases:


*** `OpenCVFrameGrabber.getDeviceDescriptions()` - `Device enumeration not support by OpenCV.`


*** `FFmpegFrameGrabber.getDeviceDescriptions()` - `Device enumeration not support by FFmpeg.`


*** `VideoInputFrameGrabber.getDeviceDescriptions()` - `Platform “linux-x86_64“ not supported by class org.bytedeco.videoinput.global.videoInputLib`

Comment: There's some work being done on that by Alan White: https://groups.google.com/g/javacpp-project/c/3QcfcTb7Eq8